# Having child class call parent class

Tags: php, oop

I sometimes find myself performing a similar task on various different related things.  For instance, I might have "books", "movies", and "songs", and I might have the task "addNote" which gets the note text from the client, adds it to a database, associates it with the appropriate parent record, and returns some data to the client.  I've implemented it as shown below, and while it works, it just seems wrong.  Is there a better way to do this, and if so how?  Thanks

```
class parentClass
{
    protected function someTask($table)
    {
        //do the task which is common to child1/2/3Class using $table
    }
}

class child1Class extends parentClass
{
    public function someTask($dummy=NULL){parent::someTask('class1_table');}
}
class child2Class extends parentClass
{
    public function someTask($dummy=NULL){parent::someTask('class2_table');}
}
class child3Class extends parentClass
{
    public function someTask($dummy=NULL){parent::someTask('class3_table');}
}

$ajax=new child1Class(); //specific childClass based on MVC
$ajax->someTask();
```

Comment: why does it seem wrong? looks pretty decent to me. Is there anything specifically bothering you?

Comment: @Raidenace I guess it seems backwards.  Usually, I create an object from the child, and it brings the parents functionality along with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have it is correct. The only other option you have is making the parent method "public"

```
class parentClass
{
    public function someTask($table)
    {
        echo "hello " . $table;
    }
}

class child1Class extends parentClass
{
  // no needed method here
}
 class child2Class extends parentClass
{
  // no needed method here
}

$obj1 = new child1Class();
$obj1->someTask('class1_table');
$obj2 = new child1Class();
$obj2->someTask('class2_table');
$obj3 = new child2Class();
$obj3->someTask('class3_table');

result with obj1: "hello class1_table"
result with obj2: "hello class2_table"
result with obj3: "hello class3_table"
```

- Public makes the method directly accessible through the object.
- Protected makes the method accessible through the child class
- Private makes the method only accessible through its own class.

Comment: Each child must implement parent::someTask() slightly differently based on the $table value sent to it.  This way doesn't do so.

Comment: Yes, now it will do so.  The application that initially creates the childClass and initiates the method does not have the capability to add a parameter.

Comment: You make objects and call the method on that object with its own parameter. It should work. I adapted the example slightly to reflect different situations. Although you now only need one child class to get the same result.

Comment: My application gets a controller and task from the client, and creates the object based on the controller, and executes the method based on the task.  Any other required data is obtained by the specific task.  I guess I had it right in the first place, but it always seems strange to me.  Thanks for your help.